# publish on wall with Facebook sdk 3.0 and Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, publish

I've read lots of tutorial and answers here, but i'm not capable to implement a button  that clicked , publish some text on the wall (with a login done programmatically). I tried with a fragment and two buttons, but this code launches a

```
05-14 09:26:32.548: E/AndroidRuntime(5080): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
```

the code is:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private static final String PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION = null;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private LoginButton login;
private Button shareButton;


private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_fragment, container, false);

    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    login=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    login.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSIONS);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = 
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
    }
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishStory();        
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);

    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
    if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
            state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
        publishStory();
    }
}

private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {

            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
                postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
                postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
                postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");

                Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                        String postId = null;
                        try {
                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                        }
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), postId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                };

                Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                task.execute();
    }

}
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

where's the problem? i'm going crazy! Thanks very  much!

Comment: I actually have the exact same problem. Did you figure out your issue?

Comment: i've changed my code at all, re-writing it similar.....if you want here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835999/publishing-on-faccebook-with-sdk-3-0-and-android-doesnt-work   i posted my entire new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're explicitly calling onSessionStateChange in your onResume method, where the callback will have called it anyways (via onActivityResult, when your permission request comes back). This results in 2 publish permission requests simultaneously, which is why you're seeing this error. Try removing the onSessionStateChange method in your onResume().

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried but nothing has changed...same error...
05-15 08:06:14.612: E/AndroidRuntime(393):  at com.example.informavenezia.FFacebook.publishStory(FFacebook.java:146)
this is the piece of code that launches the exception

Comment: Where do you open the session in the first place, is it in the same activity?

Comment: Hey @MingLi I have the same problem, except my use case is slightly different. In either case its basically the exact same code in the tutorials on the developers site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827469/keep-getting-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-requesting-a-new-permission/16828143?noredirect=1#comment24299732_16828143