# Keep getting an UnsupportedOperationException when requesting a new permission

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to the facebook sdk, so I am not really too sure why I am getting this error. I have narrowed it down to this section:

```
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS); 
       Here>> session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest); <<Here
            return;
        } //this code is located below in the publishStory() method
```

I followed both the [Authenticate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) tutorial, and the [Publish Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) tutorial exactly as is, with a bit of reordering to suit my needs. I am not sure what I could have possibly missed. I will post the `SelectionFragment` class, which I put the post status stuff to because its where a user is logged in. Just to make sure this is clear, logging in works perfectly. But when I try to click post status it does nothing. The second time I click it, it crashes. Any explanation would be most appreciated.

---

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView userNameView;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


    private Button shareButton;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    protected static final String TAG = "SelectionFragment.java";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }//end of onCreate()

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, container, false);

        // Find the user's profile picture custom view
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

        // Find the user's name view
        userNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);

        //find the share button
        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publishStory();        
            }
        });

        // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = 
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }

        return view;
    }//end of onCreateView

    /*
     * Private method that requests users data
     * */
    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                        // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                    }
                }
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // Handle errors, will do so later.
                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    } 

    /*
     * private method that will respond to session changes and call 
     * the makeMeRequest() method if the session's open
     * */
    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data.
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
        /*The following checks if user is logged in and hides or shows the share button*/
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }//end of onSessionStateChanged

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }


    /*
     * What actually publishes the status update
     * */

    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                 .getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();

        }

    }//end of publishStory

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}//end of class
```

**Edit**

Ok so I was able to finally post, but now I have figured out why its crashing still. The last method in the above class, `isSubset` seems to always return false, meaning it will always run, even if the publish permission was already created.

**Edit 2**

```
public class FacebookFrag extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS +1;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    private MenuItem settings;

    //flag that indicates a visible activity
    private boolean isResumed = false;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_layout);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(settings)) {
            showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}//end of class
```

Answer (score 2):

just **remove the return** from your publishstory();And make sure that your session is in `OPEN`   state when you call publishstory().

//

```
 if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        /* ~post your data only if session is in OPEN state also check
             for login and internet connection*/
        Session session=Session.getActiveSession();
          if(session!=null){
              MyLog.w("session state",session.getState().toString());
              if(session.getState()==SessionState.OPENED){
                  publishStory();
              }else{
                 showAlertDialog("Unable to Share"); 
              }
          }else{
               showAlertDialog("Please login first!");
          }

    }else{
        showAlertDialog("Problem occured with your internet connection");
    }
```

remove return statement

```
 if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                            .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                   `Remove this===>` return;
                }
```

Comment: The method `newPermissionsRequest` is what's crashing, meaning return is never run.

Comment: did you try above code?if not,just try it. i had same issue but removing return works for me!

Comment: Wow, it worked. You were 100% right I think I understand what was happening. The first time I tried it, it requested a new permission, but returned. The second time it tried it, it crashed because it already requested the permission. I think. Could you explain it to me more if you could?

Comment: Unfortunately its still crashes after I click on post a second time. If I am already logged in, it posts the post, but still asks me to log in again and then if I try to do it again it crashes.

Comment: The error is the same error as before. The main difference is it actually posts a status. But still crashes because `session.getPermissions()` always returns null. Thats why it only crashes every other time. So `isSubset` basically always return false. But it shouldn't!

Comment: sorry,i don't know why its happening.

Comment: please give me your activity class,maybe i can help you(i think the problem is with lifecycle of your plusClient)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you got UnsupportedOperationException, it means that the device cannot find the method that used in your app.
Something you need to check:

1. The Android version of emulator or test device must be greater than the Min SDK?
2. All the library is included and exported correctly?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense though? Eclipse wouldnt let me run it if the method is not found. If you actually look at the session class code, it throws an exception. So its finding it. But I don't know why it fails.